# Why does this relative error work?

Tags: numerical-methods

Assuming $p$ is the exact solution and $p_n$ is a numerical approximation. My question is that why most of the numerical analysis books using
$$
\frac{|p_n-p_{n-1}|}{|p_n|}
$$
to approximate the following relative error
$$
\frac{|p_n-p|}{|p|}
$$
?

Comment: Do they really claim it approximates the relative error? Or do they just say it can be used for a stopping criterion.  If the first quantity is small, then the iterates aren't changing much anymore, suggesting the algorithm has converged.

Comment: @littleO I think you could go ahead and post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The quantity $\frac{|p_n - p_{n-1}|}{|p_n|}$ does not necessarily approximate the relative error $\frac{|p_n - p|}{|p|}$ (and I don't think numerical analysis books claim that it does).  However, $\frac{|p_n - p_{n-1}|}{|p_n|}$ can be used in a stopping criterion.  If this quantity is small, then the iterates aren't changing much anymore, which suggests that the algorithm has converged.